# Marker Clusterer Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

Hy,

I don't know why the marker clusterer don't show my markers grouped , like here : http://media.svennerberg.com/2009/01/screenshot_clusterereffect.jpg

My Code is like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.136, 11.586);

        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions); 

        var points =  []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < 600; i++) {

                var point = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.135 + Math.random(), 11.664 + Math.random()),
                    map: map,
                    title:"This is where I work"
                }); 
                points.push(point);

        }

        var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, points);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:1000px; height:1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it don't work. Who can tell my why it don't work? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :) My html file didn't load the correct json and that's why it didn't worked out

Comment: what json did you need to load for this to work? and how did you fix it?

Comment: sorry dude. It was a long time ago, I don't know anymore what json did work for me.